# Is there a programming language that reads right to left?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm quite sure that modern industrial strength programming languages, all read **left to right**

But out of the whole ecosystem of [programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages) are there examples of **right to left** read languages ?

Apart from better alignment with human languages that written this way, would there be any advantage in such a language?

---

examples :

```
int a = 5; // read left to right
tfel ot thgir daer // ;5 = a tni
```

Comment: Question makes no sense. A programming language does not read anything, it's you who reads programming code. It is like asking "are there numbers that are written right to left"?

Comment: @user2864740 As a trivia you don't want to know about ? "reads right to left" means that when read your eyes follow a right to left route (as opposed to Arabic or Hebrew where that's not the case). Nobody said that the language itself "reads"

Comment: There are parts of languages, where operator associativity is right-to-left, e.g.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence  @larsmans picked such an example, but saying that "C reads right to left" is simply incorrect (and I would argue that it doesn't even make sense)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about trivia not related to a specific programming problem.

Comment: @Ingo "reads right to left" is a perfectly fine English sentence. That's just how English is.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou It might be more fitting on another stack - I don't think it's a "bad" question.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I was trying to point out that programming languages don't really read left-to-right in any meaningful sense.

Comment: Seems to exist an Arabic one also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qalb_(programming_language)

Comment: @mortb I especially enjoyed the linked [article](https://mic.com/articles/130331/this-arabic-programming-language-shows-how-computers-revolve-around-the-western-world#.MwbRgpAMP)

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: Well, what the article says, about computer science being all in English so that people with other languages have to adapt, applies (in various degrees) to all of us non native English speakers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a language for children called logowriter which later got translated into hebrew as תמלילוגו, since hebrew is RTL, so was the translated language.

The תמלילוגו language was taught as part of the CS sylabus in Israeli highschools on 2008, 
http://www.csit.org.il/TSTBAG/2008/899122.pdf

Answer (score 7):

APL is a language which overcomes the inconsistencies (and difficulty in typing / parsing / executing) traditional mathematical notation by unifying certain constructs, such as:

**multi-dimensional array reduction** (where the reduce construct was first named as such)

```
      +⌿2 4 6   ⍝ Sum of a list
12
      ×⌿2 4 6   ⍝ Product of a list
48
      2 3⍴⍳6    ⍝ A 2 row, 3 column matrix
1 2 3
4 5 6
      +⌿2 3⍴⍳6  ⍝ Sum down the columns
5 7 9
```

or **the inner product**:

```
      2 3 4+.×1 0 ¯1   ⍝ Vector inner (dot) product
¯2
      +/2 3 4×1 0 ¯1   ⍝ Equivalent expression for vectors
¯2
      (2 2⍴1 0 1)(2 2⍴2 5 4 3)   ⍝ Two matrices
┌───┬───┐
│1 0│2 5│
│1 1│4 3│
└───┴───┘
      (2 2⍴1 0 1)+.×(2 2⍴2 5 4 3)   ⍝ Matrix inner product
2 5
6 8
      1 2 3 ∧.= 1 2 2   ⍝ Are all elements equal?
0
```

Since it is inspired by traditional mathematics then it follows f(g(x)):
`f g x` means apply `g` to `x` and then apply `f` to the result of that, hence **right to left**. `f(g(x))` is also valid APL.

The easiest way to demonstrate how this affects things is:

```
      84 - 12 - 1 - 13 - 28 - 9 - 6 - 15  
70
```

which gives `0` in traditional mathematic execution order. With parentheses:

```
      84 - (12 - (1 - (13 - (28 - (9 - (6 - 15))))))     ⍝ APL
70
      (((((((84 - 12) - 1) - 13) - 28) - 9) - 6) - 15)   ⍝ Traditional maths
0
```

Although it is a general purpose programming language, used for applications from finance to 3D graphics, you can see more comparisons with mathematical notation on the APL Wiki: https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Comparison_with_traditional_mathematics

---

And having said all that, APL is still generally "read" (by humans) basically left to right, even though it is parsed and executed "right-to-left", and even then it's more of "functions have a long right scope and short left scope". For example, using the statement separator `⋄` to have multiple statements in a single line:

```
      2+2 ⋄ 3 4 5 ⋄ ⎕A⍳'APL'
4
3 4 5
1 16 12
```

The left-most statements are executed *first*, but each individual statement is parsed as described above.

Answer (score 6):

## [Befunge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge) is such a language :)

```
"!dlrow olleH">:#,_@
```

Is a standard Hello world program, however this actually evaluates left-to-right.

```
<v_@#:<"Hello world!"
 >,>>>^
```

This ^ evaluates right-to-left, with some up-to-down and down-to-up movement too. You can run this program at https://www.bedroomlan.org/tools/befunge-playground/#prog=hello,mode=edit .

[Unefunge](http://quadium.net/funge/spec98.html#Whatis) is a variant without up-down movement, but it is still turing-complete. If you want strictly right-to-left programs, you can write in unefunge as long as your program starts with `<` to send the instruction pointer in the right direction.

For more information, Stack Overflow has a [befunge](/questions/tagged/befunge) tag.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but now there is [Avsha](https://kultuk.github.io/Avsha/). That is a whole new language based on Hebrew, or [ChavaScript](https://chavascript.github.io/chavascript/) that uses Hebrew words and translates them to JS in English (including variable names, that are translated when found in the dictionary, or written in with each letter translated to the relevant English letter).

Answer (score -2):

```
tfel ot thgir daer // ;5 = a tni
```

AFAIK, there are no such languages, at least, not a serious one (thanks for [tohava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25103447/650405) for the interesting example). Simply because it's mostly pointless.

You can pick any existing language, write a one liner script that reverses every line, and you have a converter (and back converter) for this "new language". You can incorporate it into your build environment - transform before compilation, reverse the lines of the compiler error messages and so on...

But really, what's the point? The only people who would benefit from this are the the ones who use right to left for their native language (BTW, AFAIK, none of them use the latin ABC). They have to learn something completely new anyways, and it makes a lot more sense to do what the rest of the world does. All the blogs, tutorial, blogs, SO, everything is written in "left-to-right" programming languages.

Comment: I found [this](https://mic.com/articles/130331/this-arabic-programming-language-shows-how-computers-revolve-around-the-western-world#.MwbRgpAMP) to be quite interesting

Comment: technicly, programming languages are read "right to left". but sometimes they are read "left to right". i.e.:             $secureSession = new \Zend\Session\Container('secureSession');
if (empty($secureSession->browser))...;