# Is there a programming language that is close to english and read purely left to right?

Tags: user-interface, language-design, readability, code-readability

Is there a programming language that is purely written left to right?

Example (close to Python syntax):

Normal Python: `a: int = 2 + 3`

Left to Right Python: `2 + 3 = a: int`

The assignment should be after the calculation, because the assignment happens after the calculation (proper representation of the thought prozess and of that happens in time)

There is one related post I found ([Is there a programming language that reads right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103273/is-there-a-programming-language-that-reads-right-to-left/25103447#25103447)) but it is several years old and was not very well formulated.

While SQL seems to be quite close to this, it is not turing complete.

Haskell would meet my criterias as far as I can see, except variable assignment, given some syntactic sugar is or is not used.

FOL, ASP, ECLiPSe and other more descriptive languages are mostly nondirected and are usually either by convention (FOL) or by definition (ASP, ECLiPSe) still right to left in some way.

I do see the UI advantages of variables being assigned being at the beginning of the line. It would still be interesting to see, if it is actually an advantage or if we are just used to it.

I am aware that I could simply create a new dialect or writing convention for some existing system to get this result, but I would also be interested into the readability of existing code in the wild etc. :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Forth is probably the closest.

Comment: @SK-logic thank you for your response but Reverse Polish Notation is pretty much the opposite of what I am looking for. (a 4 5 + vs. 4 + 5 = a)

Comment: Right... For this you'll probably need a language with a flexible syntax then. For example, see the reverse assignment implementation here: https://github.com/combinatorylogic/clike/blob/master/tests/syntax.c

Comment: prolog allows `=` to be reversed, but it might not be much like what you're looking for.